# Why I am getting error c2512 : no appropriate default constructor availiable?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement the templated class MyQueue(Logical structure is ring buffer):

```
// MyQueue.h
#pragma once
template<typename T>
class MyQueue
{
public:
    /* interface */
    MyQueue(int sizeOfBuffer);
    void push(const T& elem);
    T pop(void);

private:
    T* m_array;
};

template<typename T>
MyQueue<T>::MyQueue(int sizeOfBuffer)
{
    m_array = new T[sizeOfBuffer];
}
```

Usually when I face implementation of a constructor in a template class I implement it in declaration:

```
#pragma once
template<typename T>
class MyQueue
{
public:
    /* interface */
    MyQueue(int sizeOfBuffer){// do some actions with argument sizeOfBuffer};
    void push(const T& elem);
    T pop(void);

private:
    T* m_array;
};
```

*As body of constructor can occupy a lot of space I decided to implement it apart from declaration(but in the same header) to make code more readable*.
**Question:** what I am doing wrong and how to solve my issue?

Comment: What `T` are you using in the specialization that you are instantiating?

Comment: please show the full error message and also the code which uses `MyQueue<int>`

Comment: The full error message shows you *which line of which file* caused the error.  Don't keep it a secret.

Comment: Thanks for question, I spotted the error it was due to I ommited argument for the constructor in cpp file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with how you've written the body of your constructor.

It has to do with the fact that somewhere you're apparently trying to create a default-constructed object of this class, but you haven't provided a default constructor. Normally, the compiler would synthesize a default constructor, but since you've written a constructor that takes an argument, the compiler won't do that (automatically) either.

With a recent compiler, you should be able to get the default constructor synthesized using the `= default;` syntax introduced in C++11. Otherwise, you'll need to write one explicitly, or add a default argument to your existing constructor (e.g., `MyQueue(int sizeOfBuffer = 20);`).

Comment: Thanks for response. Issue was due to I tried to instantiate object of T with no arguments.